# Why are "~B" and "$\{x : x\notin B\}$" not the same thing? Trying to understand basic set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why are they different: "~B" vs. $\{x:x \notin B\}$?  They both mean elements not in B. As long as that's satisfied, it should work, right?

How we use them in class:
$A\setminus B$ = {$x: x \in A \text{ and } x\notin B $}
$x \in A\setminus B$  iff $(x \in A) \land (x \notin B)$

**Example:**
Let B = {2, 4, 6, 8}.

> the integers 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
> the real numbers greater than 25
> the function $f(x)=x^2+3$
> the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin of the plane
> the Empire State Building
> my uncle Wilbur

**Solution explains they are different:**
$\{x:x \notin B\}$ contains all of the above.
1, 3, 5, 7 should be included in "~B", and perhaps real numbers greater than 25. But, most likely not the others. And certainly, knowing that my uncle Wilbur is not a member of the set B would contribute little to any discussion of B.

**Question:**
What's wrong with including the others? They are clearly not in B. I'm so confused right now.

Comment: What is the definition of ~B that you are given?

Comment: The expression ~B means not B and implies that B is a proposition. Are you thinking ~B means B complement?

Comment: They are the same thing, assuming you're working within some universal set $U.$ That is, all sets in question, including $B$ must be subsets of $U.$ Otherwise, set-builder notation cannot be used like that.

Comment: I think you are working with some kind of space, where $B$ is a subset. Like, for example, in a metric space $(X, d)$ we define the complement of a subset $S$ as $\{ x \in X | x \notin S\}$. And that is usually what we mean when working with complements. They are defined with respect to some big set. In fact, we use notations such as $\sim B$ or $\overline B$ when it is clear from context what is this big set. Otherwise we should use notations like $\complement_{\mathbb R}(B)$ or $\mathbb R \setminus B$

Comment: Regarding complement. Let me add to my question here. Give me a sec to update!

Comment: Post updated with relevant context

Comment: I see why your answer is incorrect. As mentioned above by @Favst, you have to know the universe in which you are working. If the universe is the integers, for example, then circles and functions wouldn't be in the complement.

Comment: My answer was taken from the solution. I'm almost copying from word-to-word here. Unless the solution is wrong.

Comment: I've added more to the solution now. Hopefully, you see the confusion I'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

When taking the complement of some set we are (at least implicitly) working with some sort of universal set in the background. In your example, the universal set $X$ could be the set of all integers $\mathbb{Z}$, or the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, or the set $\{2,4,6,8\}\cup C$, where $C$ is the set of all cows. You can't meaningfully take the complement of a set unless you know what its background set is.

(In some sense, [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) is an extreme example of how things can break when you haven't specified your background set.)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments indicate, the expression ~$B$ implicitly assumes a universe $U$ of possible elements some of which may be in the subset $B$.

Both the first two possible answers require a very improbable universe $U$. The third even more so. The last two are not even statements about mathematical objects, so make no sense at all.

Comment: I've edited the solution just now. The solution explicitly points out they are different.

Comment: Ok, I think it's probably under a universe $U$, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's true that the notion of "complement of a set" presupposes some notion of universal set, I would expect this universal set to include all the entities under discussion, even Wilbur, unless the contrary was explicitly stated in the question. And I don't consider "would contribute little to any discussion" relevant at all. Mathematical entities like sets don't exist solely to contribute to our discussions. As far as I'm concerned, that "solution", considered as mathematics, is hopelessly confused.